# I can't connect a button with an action

Tags: ios, xcode, button, uibutton, action

I'm not sure know what I did but when I drag a button into the header file and when i click connection, there is only outlet, and outlet collection, no action. I have tried to open up another x code project and I can make a button with an action but not the one with all my code in it.

Comment: No, i never had to do that. when I open a new project and just hold down control and drag it, i can make an action connection. im thinking when i was editing I accidentally deleted something that I shouldnt have

Comment: Does the project compile?  Can you drag a button in a different uiviewcontroller to a different header file in this project?  Can you post some code from that header file, maybe there is something there that prevents you creating actions.

Comment: I just realized that when i drag a button into the header file on my first viewcontroller I can make an action. but on my second I can only make an outlet and outlet collection. Is there something specific I have to do when creating a new viewcontroller? sorry Im new to Xcode

Answer (score 1):

Just make an IBAction method in your code...

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
```

This will alert the compiler that you want an action to show up in your connections inspector.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two nib file of same class then you need to select class for your nib file. select your nib file>select File's>select class [Picture-1]

Then you connect your outlet to the view [Picture-2]. Now you connect every item with your class object...

[image: Picture-1]

[image: Picture-2]

Happy Coding...